# How to extract two specific characters of a column name and attach them to another column name?

Tags: python, substring, extract

I have a dataset with a 1000+ column. Around 100 columns contain among others, the text: `insured`. For each of these columns, two columns to the right there is a column that amongst others, contains either the characters '3%' or '4%'. What I need to do is extract the substring '3%' or '4%' and add that to the column containing the word `insured`, resulting in for example: `insured 3%`.

So far, I have the following code:

```
# Find all columns containing the word 'Insured'
insured_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Insured' in col]

# Get the index of these columns
insured_index = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in insured_cols if c in df]

# Get the index of the columns that I want to extract either '3%' or '4%' from
percentage_index = [x + 2 for x in insured_index]

# Get dataframe of these columns
percentage_cols = page.iloc[:,percentage_index]
```

The next step would be to extract the substring '3%' or '4%' from `percentage_cols` and to add this to the column names of `insured cols`.

I hope that my question is clear enough, please let me know if further clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if you can paste part of list of columns of your dataframe. Based on my understanding I generated dummy columns implemented the solution you want

```py
cols = "column1 insured x y jpt3%  column2 column3 insured z p jjj4%".split()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10,len(cols))), columns=cols)

new_columns = list(df.columns)
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if "insured" in col:
        percent_text = "3%" if df.columns[i+3].find("3%")>-1 else "4%"
        new_columns[i] = col + percent_text

df.columns = new_columns
df
```

Comment: Changed new_columns[i] = col+" 3%" to new_columns[i] = col+ " " + percent_text and then it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
    indexes = numpy.where(percentage_cols=='3%')
    for index in indexes
        insured cols.append(percentage_cols[index])
        np.delete(percentage_cols, percentage_cols[index], axis=0)
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't. The percentage_cols contain amongst others the substring 3% or 4%, but it never exactly matches the whole string.

Comment: https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-string-contains/

`indexes = numpy.where('3%' in percentage_cols)`